# Node.js Socket.io HTTPS - transport polling

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, https, socket.io

I am using nginx with my ssl certificates and it's giving me the https version of my site which is great. The problem is my socket.io communications don't work unless i use a regular http connection. I apologize if this is a bit long, but i'm not sure what i'm doing here and wanted to make sure you guys had everything you might need to know. I have tried the solutions of various different sites some of which were on here, but none of them worked.

I tried manually creating the https server instead of letting express do it but that resulted in nothing loading at all, with the current implementation i can at least see the site.

```
upstream project {
   server example.org:4000;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   return https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl default_server;
   listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
   ssl_certificate /home/adam/SSL/public.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /home/adam/SSL/example.org.key;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

   location / {
     proxy_pass http://example.org;
   }
}
```

That seems to be working as when i go to my site, it automatically takes me to the https version and the page is loaded. The issue is when is when the client side tries to connect i keep getting:

"https://MY_SERVER_IP:4040/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M0CPjUDnet::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED"

printed to the console

Here's my client and server code:

```
var IPaddress = 'https://MY_SERVER_IP:4040';
var socket = io.connect(IPaddress,{secure:true});
socket.on('connect', function (socket) {
    console.log('Connected!');
});
```

server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/SSL/example.com.key','utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/SSL/public.crt','utf8');
var intermediate = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/SSL/intermediate.crt','utf8');
var options = {key:privateKey,cert:certificate,ca:intermediate};

var io = require('socket.io').listen(4040,options);
//var io = require('socket.io').listen(4040);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
       console.log("A client has left us :(");
    });
});
app.listen(4000);
```

---

### Update - 02/12/2017

In my code i have this line:

```
require('./routes.js')(app);
```

which contains:

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    app.get('/main',function(req,res){
        if (req.session.user == null){
            // if user is not logged-in redirect back to login page //
            res.redirect('/');
        }   else{
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/FrontEnd/main.html'));
        }
    });

    // viewed at http://localhost:8080
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        if(req.cookies.user == undefined || req.cookies.pass == undefined){
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/FrontEnd/login.html'));
        }else {
            //attempt automatic login
            AM.autoLogin(req.cookies.user,req.cookies.pass,function(o){
               if(o !=null){
                   req.session.user = o;
                   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/FrontEnd/home.html'));
               }else{
                   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/FrontEnd/login.html'));
               }
            });

        }
    });
```

......

Could this be causing the 502 bad gateway error?

Comment: The socket.io `listen(port[, options])` function only accepts HTTP connections, not HTTPS. Your approach of manually creating the HTTPS server and attaching socket.io/express to it was correct. Can you include that non-working code in your question as well?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment, in your current server code, both express and socket.io are only accepting regular HTTP connections. The socket.io `listen(port[, options])` function does not accept HTTPS connections.

You started on the right approach with manually creating an HTTPS server. You then need to attach express and socket.io to that server.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/SSL/example.com.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/SSL/public.crt', 'utf8');
var intermediate = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/SSL/intermediate.crt', 'utf8');
var options = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate, ca: intermediate };

// Create our HTTPS server here and attach express to it
var server = require('https').createServer(options, app);

// Attach socket.io to our existing HTTPS server
var io = require('socket.io')(server); 

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
       console.log("A client has left us :(");
    });
});
server.listen(4000);
```

Comment: hi, i changed my code to match your answer but when i try to access my site i get a "502 Bad Gateway" error.

Comment: ok, i fixed the 502 bad gateway error but i am still getting the transport polling issue.

Comment: In the code you posted, your client connects to port 4040 but your server is listening on port 4000. That may be your issue.

Comment: @user7856951 i am also experiencing transport polling and 502 error. how did u resolve it. in my case, on client side, i simply give the https domain url like https://api.mydomain.com - no port here.